# external CSS and HTML not linking

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting out with HTML and CSS and I can't figure out why my CSS won't link to my HTML template.

Index.html and style.css are in the same folder currently, and the css works fine when it's internal.  Am I missing something obvious?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">       
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="header">
        <a href="#default" class="logo">header</a>
        <div class="header-right">
          <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
      <h5>footer</h5>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: the problem seems to be some sort of compatibility issue.  In safari a selected my own style sheet in preferences and it worked properly (I couldn't figure out how to do it in chrome). This doesn't seem like a permanent solution though?

Comment: Maybe, rendered template is served on another path (as axample, `/about`). If so, your CSS file is searched at location `/about/style.css`, but not just `/style.css`. Consider **using absolute file path**

Comment: Try with `./styles.css`. Also, make sure your webserver serves css files as text.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with putting the path of the file by using "./path" and see if it works also check whether your webserver takes your css files as text as you have given type as text/css.

Comment: I'm pretty fresh to programming, can you explain how to check the web server settings?  Does it matter that if I take out the "type" attribute nothing changes?  I'm almost positive the problem isn't the file path since I've tried various paths and types.